# Spring + Logback(slf4j) logging without jcl-over-slf4j

Tags: java, spring, maven, logging, logback

If i add Logback and Slf4j to my Spring MVC (version 4.1.0) project by adding maven dependencies like this:

```
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
                <version>1.7.21</version>
                <scope>runtime</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                <version>1.7.21</version>
                <scope>compile</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.7</version>
                <scope>runtime</scope>
            </dependency>
```

and exclude commons-logging dependency, then i get in log file, in addition to application logs, some spring events INFO level like:

```
[RMI TCP Connection(4)-127.0.0.1][org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader] - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
```

If i add dependencies without jcl-over-slf4j, and without excluding commons-logging in pom.xml, then i get only application logs.

This is my logback.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>

    <property name="LOG_HOME" value="logs" />
    <property name="APP_NAME" value="App" />

    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">        
        <encoder>
            <charset>UTF-8</charset>
            <pattern>%-5level %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %thread %logger{50} - %msg%n</pattern>            
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <appender name="FILE"  class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <FileNamePattern>${LOG_HOME}/${APP_NAME}.log.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</FileNamePattern>
            <MaxHistory>30</MaxHistory>
        </rollingPolicy>

        <encoder>
            <charset>UTF-8</charset>
            <pattern>%-5level %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} %thread %logger{50} - %msg%n</pattern>                
        </encoder>

        <triggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy">
            <MaxFileSize>10MB</MaxFileSize>
        </triggeringPolicy>
    </appender>  

    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
        <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
    </root>

    <logger name="org.springframework" level="INFO" appender-ref="FILE"/>
</configuration>
```

As i understand it, this happens because when i don't use the JCL-bridge, logback can't catch, or translate JCL spring inner logs. Please, correct me, if i am wrong.

Can i configure logback.xml for getting standart spring log events without JCL-bridge?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check theirs [docs](https://spring.io/blog/2009/12/04/logging-dependencies-in-spring/), because it is a good source for information with a lot of examples.
Back to your question:
Spring and JCL:

> The mandatory logging dependency in Spring is the Jakarta Commons
> Logging API (JCL). We compile against JCL and we also make JCL Log
> objects visible for classes that extend the Spring Framework. It’s
> important to users that all versions of Spring use the same logging
> library: migration is easy because backwards compatibility is
> preserved even with applications that extend Spring.The way we do this
> is to make one of the modules in Spring depend explicitly on
> commons-logging (the canonical implementation of JCL), and then make
> all the other modules depend on that at compile time. If you are using
> Maven for example, and wondering where you picked up the dependency on
> commons-logging, then it is from Spring and specifically from the
> central module calledspring-core.

Logback configuration, here is good point:

> A more common choice amongst SLF4J users, which uses fewer step sand
> generates fewer dependencies, is to bind directly to Logback. This
> removes the extra binding step because **Logback implements SLF4J
> directly, so you only need to depend on two libaries not four
> (jcl-over-slf4j and logback)**. If you do that you might also need to
> exclude the slf4j-api dependency from other external dependencies (not
> Spring), because you only want one version of that API on the
> classpath.